# polymorphism applied to the lock method

Tags: c#

I have to implement my own locking, but be able to use the standard C# lock if that option is selected as well. I'd like to do this with polymorphism but am stumped as to how to do that for a method like lock.

Is there some way to pass a method as the result of a method, like lock?

Comment: Perhaps you should add an example of what you want to achieve as its not very clear from your question.

Comment: Why do you think you need to implement your own locking? Polymorphism has nothing to do with concurrency, they refer to completely different fields. It's not even apples to oranges, it's apples to traffic lights

Comment: Are you trying to implement versioning or checkout/checkin functionality? Just because the name `lock` is used in that context doesn't mean that the `lock` keyword is suitable.

Comment: "Go and implement your own locking" seems like the modern equivalent to ["go to the stores and ask for a long weight/wait"](http://messybeast.com/dragonqueen/fools-errands.htm)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's for a school assignment, I have to be able to switch between my own implementation of locking and C#'s standard one, the most elegant way in my mind to switch between the locking methods would be using polymorphism, so I'm merely trying to see if that option exists. Seems like it doesn't, at least not in an elegant way, so I'll be looking at other options.

Comment: @RachelvandenBroek that would make sense only if you wanted to use a different synchronization primitive. In that case, use `using`. `lock` was added *before* `IDisposable` was introduced. The language designers said they'd use `using` if it was available.

Comment: @RachelvandenBroek or you could use `async/await` to await a different primitive. You can use [SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) to "block" on a SemaphoreSlim

Comment: Downvoters, realize you are downvoting something *Jon Skeet* [wrote about](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/alternative.shtml) back in 2004!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock` is currently defined purely in terms of `Monitor.Enter` / `Monitor.Exit`. It is *theoretically possible* that this might change in the future (for example, `fixed` changed recently to include the ability to write custom implementations via `GetPinnableReference()`), but: not today. You can probably achieve something similar with `using`, returning something `IDisposable` that does the code you want.

Comment: I remember one of the C# designers saying they'd use `using` blocks instead of locks if they were available in C# 1

Comment: Found a relevant article by Jon Skeet [An Alternative Approach to Monitors](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/alternative.shtml). From 2004! He had already created a library for this back then